# How dynamically replace keyframes value in css animation while using boolean in state?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I created slide animation for my drop out menu, now I need to change the keyframes to make this menu not just disappear but smoothly hide in the same way it appears on the screen.

The issue is that I'm missing something or using the incorrect syntax for some of my approaches.

link to the repo:
https://github.com/kkdima/barva

[image: screenrec of the issue]

For styling, I'm using styled-components, because it has these ThemeProvider features and variables options.
I was trying to fix this with the ThemeProvider but no success so far. It gives messages that something wrong with the props.

Also, I have 2 components in the same .js file, one of them is sharing state with another.
`this.state = { menuTriggered: false };`
this state is the reference to which keyframe should be animated, either bgAnimationOpen or bgAnimationClose.
In both of them, I have elements (Background and Ul) which need to be changed for the smooth backward animation.

The next code example has needed keyframes in the definition of Background div. The rest are stored in the separate KeyFrames.js file which I import.

Pardon me for such a long code, I just have styles inside my js files.

```
import Link from "next/link";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import styled, { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import Logo from "./Logo";

import { menuAnimationOpen } from "../styles/KeyFrames";
import { menuToClose } from "../styles/KeyFrames";
import { closeToMenu } from "../styles/KeyFrames";
import { MenuToCloseBackwards } from "../styles/KeyFrames";
import { bgAnimationOpen } from "../styles/KeyFrames";
import { bgAnimationClose } from "../styles/KeyFrames";

class Menu extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const { menuTriggered } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                    <Background />
                </ThemeProvider>

                <UL className="menuOpens">
                    <StyledLink href="/">
                        <Li>
                            <A>Home</A>
                        </Li>
                    </StyledLink>

                    <StyledLink href="/projects">
                        <Li>
                            <A>Projects</A>
                        </Li>
                    </StyledLink>

                    <StyledLink href="/about">
                        <Li>
                            <A>About</A>
                        </Li>
                    </StyledLink>

                    <StyledLink href="/contact">
                        <Li>
                            <A>Contact</A>
                        </Li>
                    </StyledLink>
                </UL>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


class SlideNav extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { menuTriggered: false };
    }

    toggleMenu = () => {
        this.setState({ menuTriggered: !this.state.menuTriggered });
    };

    render() {
        const { menuTriggered } = this.state;
        return (
            <MenuWrapper className="menu">
                <LogoAndMenuButton>
                    <Logo />
                    <MenuTextWrapper>
                        <Input type="checkbox" onClick={this.toggleMenu} />
                        <Span className="text-Menu">
                            <p>Menu</p>
                        </Span>
                        <Span className="text-Close">
                            <p>Close</p>
                        </Span>
                    </MenuTextWrapper>
                </LogoAndMenuButton>
                {menuTriggered ? (
                    <Menu
                        menuTriggered={this.state.menuTriggered}
                    >
                        {/* {this.props.children} */}
                    </Menu>
                ) : (
                    <div />
                )}
            </MenuWrapper>
        );
    }
}

export default SlideNav;


const StyledLink = styled(Link)``;

const MenuWrapper = styled.div`
    width: 100vw;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 40;
    background: grey;
`;

const LogoAndMenuButton = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
`;

// MENU/CLOSE BUTTON STYLES:
// MENU/CLOSE BUTTON STYLES:
// MENU/CLOSE BUTTON STYLES:
const MenuTextWrapper = styled.div`
    background: none;
    border: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 65px;
    height: 26px;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 40px 40px;

    /* Menu to Close text animation 1st span  */
    input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .text-Menu {
        animation: ${menuToClose} 300ms ease-in-out;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    /* Menu to Close text animation 2nd span  */
    input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .text-Close {
        color: #fff;
        animation: ${closeToMenu} 300ms ease-in-out;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    /* Close to Menu text animation 2nd span  */
    input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) ~ .text-Menu {
        animation: ${MenuToCloseBackwards} 300ms ease-in-out;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
`;

const Input = styled.input`
    position: absolute;
    width: 65px;
    height: 26px;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
`;

const Span = styled.span`
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    color: black;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    z-index: -1;
    p {
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        margin: 0;
    }
`;
//END OF MENU/CLOSE BUTTON STYLES;
//END OF MENU/CLOSE BUTTON STYLES;
//END OF MENU/CLOSE BUTTON STYLES;

const menuOpen = bgAnimationOpen, menuClose = bgAnimationClose;

const Background = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #222222;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;

    @keyframes bgAnimationOpen {
        from {
            transform: translateY(-900px);
        }
        to {
            visibility: block;
        }
    }

    @keyframes bgAnimationClose {
        from {
            transform: translateY(900px);
        }
        to {
            visibility: block;
        }
    }

    animation: ${bgAnimationOpen} 0.8s
        cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
`;

Background.defaultProps = {
    theme: {
        open: "bgAnimationOpen"
    }
};

const theme = {
    close: "bgAnimationClose",
    open: "bgAnimationOpen"
};

// UL NAVIGATION STYLES:
// UL NAVIGATION STYLES:
// UL NAVIGATION STYLES:
const UL = styled.ul`
    position: absolute;
    top: 140px;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: bold;
    max-width: 200px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 40px;
    padding: 0px;

    li:nth-of-type(1) {
        animation: ${menuAnimationOpen} 0.8s 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.35, 0.25, 0, 1.28);
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    li:nth-of-type(2) {
        animation: ${menuAnimationOpen} 0.8s 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.35, 0.25, 0, 1.22);
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    li:nth-of-type(3) {
        animation: ${menuAnimationOpen} 0.8s 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.35, 0.25, 0, 1.15);
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    li:nth-of-type(4) {
        animation: ${menuAnimationOpen} 0.8s 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.35, 0.25, 0, 1.1);
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
`;

const Li = styled.li`
    opacity: 0;
    list-style: none;
    color: pink;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 45px;

    transition: transform 400ms ease-in;
    &:hover {
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
`;

const A = styled.a`
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
`;
```

The needed outcome is working animation back and force just as on the attached gif. Much love if you can help with any clue to resolving this!

PS. It's slightly out of topic but maybe somebody knows how to fix the gif in the logo background? In the end of the cycle or in the very beggining it dissapears and creates delay in couple sec where there's no gif background. How to keep it in the loop all the time with no dissapearence? even though it's on the loop by default

```
animation: gifs 60s infinite running;
```